# Are Americans allowed to enter Germany with only a D visa under Covid restrictions?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, covid-19

I am a US citizen residing in the US and I have accepted a job in Germany. My company is sponsoring me for a Blue Card. I have a valid D visa, the letter from my employer regarding the need for my presence in Germany *(Präsenzbescheinigung),* and of course I will complete the digital registration before I leave.

My local consulate told me I will be able to enter with these documents but I cannot confirm that from the government website. According to [this site](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/coronavirus#content_0), entry is possible from EU states, Schengen states, the UK, and other countries which are evaluated to be a low Covid risk by the EU. Entries from all other countries are allowed under [urgent need](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/travel-restrictions-border-control/travel-restriction-border-control-list.html#f14104798), which includes family reunification (does not apply to me) and people who are returning to their homes in Germany (does not apply to me because I am moving there for the first time). Maybe I am missing something, but it seems like my situation isn't covered under these rules and I would not be allowed entry.

Will my D visa be enough to enter, or am I likely to be turned away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would fall under the exemption category [Skilled or highly qualified foreign workers](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/travel-restrictions-border-control/which-skilled-and-highly-qualified-foreign-workersare-permitted-to-enter-Germany.html).

Plus, they would not have issued you a national visa if you did not qualify for an exemption.

Note that permission to enter does not exempt you from the obligations under public health orders in effect such as testing and isolation/quarantine requirements.

Comment: The **Federal Ministry of the Interior** (responsible for Border Control) is the relevant page for such information: [BMI - News - Important information about border checks and travel restrictions due to the corona pandemic](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/kurzmeldungen/EN/2020/03/corona-ein-und-ausreise-en.html): *Persons who are not EU citizens who have a long-term right of residence (residence permit **or long-term visa**) in an EU member state...* Your **D-Visa** is a **long-term visa**, so this confirms the consulate information.